# Linq Return grouped result

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have the following database entity containing ingredients to put on pizza. Column Type is a foreign key to another table containing information on the ingredient category (cheese, meat, vegetables etc.)

```
public class Ingredient
{
    public int IngredientId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool IsVegetarian { get; set; }

    public int Type { get; set; }
}
```

Some sample data:
[sample ingredients](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLT3X.png)

For each unique 'Type' value, I want to return a List of Ingredients with that type.
The final result will be stored in an ICollection of type IngredientViewModel.

```
public class IngredientViewModel : Model
{
    public IngredientCategory Category { get; set; }

    public List<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }
}
```

How can I best get all ingredients, grouped per category in a single database trip using linq or lambda expressions?

I currently have the following snippet which I find a bit messy:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<IngredientViewModel>> GetIngredientsPerCategoryAsync()
{
        IEnumerable<Ingredient> result = await _repo.GetAllAsync();

        IEnumerable<IngredientViewModel> viewModels = result.GroupBy(
            x => x.Type,
            (category, ingredients) => new IngredientViewModel()
            {
                Category = (IngredientCategory)category,
                Ingredients = MapFromEntities(ingredients)
            })
            .OrderBy(x => x.Category.ToString())
            .ToList();

        return viewModels;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7325278

Comment: What have you tried you so far, and where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most obvious would be: `Ingredients = g.ToList()`.